# Display Latitude and Longitude in billing and shipping address and display value on admin panel order section

Tags: shipping-address, billing-address, custom-field, order-grid, magento2.4.6

Add new fields(Latitude, Longitude) in billing address and shipping address and display both custom fields and it's value on following sections:

- Admin Order Section
- Order notification and email address section
- Order PDF address section